# How to model "change" in a database and object orientation

Tags: java, database, oop

I haven't had much to do with OOP for some time now and I am uncertain how to approach the following problem. To refresh my knowledge I decided to do a small program in java.

The main problem lies in the modelling of three classes. So there exists an abstract base class like human and child classes Mother, Father, Child. Mother and Father can have multiple kids. But a kid can become a parent aswell and have children and so forth. I haven't considered the idea of working with interfaces yet.
Personally the second approach seems more accurate but I am not sure. And how would I model that in a database.

**Edit**: To specify what i meant: In my case there are certain attributes that a mother/father has but a child doesn't, therefore my approach with the hierarchy. And with change i meant that at some point the child might become a parent aswell and thus having children. Sorry for the confusion i didn't mean to say that my scribble is a uml diagramm but rather a visual representation of what i thought of.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to express with your diagram, but it's definitely not UML

Comment: Are you talking about inheritance relationships or ownership relationships? Also your title mentions monitoring "change" but your question does not, can you clarify?

Comment: One way would be to have a `Person` table and for each `Person` row have foreign keys to `Mother` and `Father`.  The `Person` row would also have a child/adult `boolean` flag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "In my case there are certain attributes that a mother/father has but a child doesn't" -- Such as... ?

Comment: Well i thought of something like the date of passing the driver license or the date when a woman becomes pregnant @JasonC

Comment: It's the same, they're all humans. Every human has a date of conception so that would be a property of a human (mothers can have more than one date of pregnancy so it would be needlessly complicated to make it a property of the mother and associate it with children, just make it a property of the child; and the mother herself also has a date that she was conceived). Every human has either passed a drivers license test or not so that's a nullable date property of a human.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. So are you suggesting that i take the approach with human, mother, child as individual classes or just a human class?

Comment: Just a human class. Properties include "mother", "father", "date of conception", "driver's license date" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create separate classes for the various members of a family, because:

- Every member is a human.
- Every human has parents (even mothers and fathers have mothers and fathers).
- Every human may or may not have children.

So every person in your database, whether they're a mother or a father or a child, has:

- A biological mother (link to one other human).
- A biological father (link to one other human).
- Zero or more children (links to zero or more other humans). But you don't necessarily need to represent this in the database, since it's implied by the links to parents.

So you can just model them all as Humans with those properties, and they can all be in the same table of humans. If a "child" ends up having children, just add to its set of children.

It's up to you if you want to store parent <-> child links in a separate table or not. Depends on your situation, what your DBMS likes, etc. If you'd like to cover the possibility of unknown parents then you can make the mother and father links optional.

Other properties, such as gender, age, adulthood status, whatever, are extra things you can add if you'd like but generally speaking they're all humans with a hierarchical structure.

Comment: Note that if you store a biological gender with each human and then drop the separate "mother" and "father" columns (just storing links to parents or links to children) then "mother" vs "father" can be inferred from biological gender at the expense of extra query complexity, the benefit being you remove the possibilities of inconsistencies such as having "mother" point to a male. Social norms notwithstanding.